# What's the efficiency of real heat engines?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

Real heat engines always have lower efficiency than the Carnot efficiency.

I wonder how efficient real engines can be? Can their efficiency get anywhere near the Carnot-limit?

Comment: I have been thinking a bit more about your question and have written an "appendix" to my answer.

Comment: Glad my additions seemed to answer your question. Thanks for asking it: I'm not an energy technologist but it piqued my interest and I learnt a great deal answering it. It's surprisingly hard to dig out answers in pure thermodynamic theoretical terms: the people really in the know about this stuff don't seem to think in this way: I found myself ringing engineers in the Latrobe Valley where most of the electricity where I live is generated, and the people I spoke to there simply did not think in terms of Carnot efficiency at all. what I eventually found, as stated in my answer, was that we...

Comment: ... seem to be doing a rather good job these days of squeezing something approaching Carnot efficiency out of our heat engines. I saw some years ago (about 2007) quite a whacky piece of research into millimetre sized steam turbines powered by tiny solar collectors: believe it or not, this was touted as a possible energy source for laptops and other small appliances. The materials used were advanced ceramics, tungsten (wolfram), iridium and so forth and the steam temperatures mooted were stupendous: I can't seem to find it now but these guys were aiming for >70% efficiency.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance 70% is nice. A heat engine like that could sustain the JET tokamak on its own power while feeding some energy into the grid. A fusion power plant need a very efficient heat engine, since the gain factors of fusion efforts is still quite low, so they require a very efficient energy recirculation to run on their own power.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most efficient heat engines are invariably the biggest and slowest working. For a steam turbine, "slowest working" means having many turbine stages, so that work is extracted from the steam as it "slowly" expands in many stages, doing a small amount of work against many turbine stages. The high thermal stability of a very big system means that a wide difference between the upper and lower reservoir temperatures can be upheld, and thus a high potential Carnot efficiency. A reciprocating engine's efficiency is generally improved by making it run very slowly: one or two hertz maximum.

The [Steam-Electric Power Station Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam-electric_power_station) states actual efficiencies of big steam electricity plants of between 33% and 48%. Assuming the steam turbine can exhaust at, say 100C (373K), if the 48% were near to the Carnot efficiency, this would mean an upper reservoir temperature $T_{max}$ given by:

$$1-\frac{T_{min}}{T_{max}} = \eta \Leftrightarrow T_{max} = \frac{T_{min}}{1-\eta} = \frac{373}{1-0.48} = 720K$$

This is somewhat below what contemporary technology can superheat steam to; from the article:

[V Ganapathy, "Superheaters: design and performance", Hydrocarbon Processing, July 2001](http://v_ganapathy.tripod.com/superhtr.pdf)

I glean rough temperatures of 1300K (2000F) as being within the reach of a radiant superheater. This would imply a Carnot efficiency of

$$\eta = 1-\frac{T_{min}}{T_{max}} = 1-\frac{373}{1300} = 71\%$$

So it would seem that even at these high efficiencies, we're working rather below the Carnot efficiency. It would be good to get the input from an energy technologist at this point to firm some of these figures up.

The Earth's biggest internal combustion engine is the [Wärtsilä-Sulzer RTA96-C](http://www.emma-maersk.com/engine/Wartsila_Sulzer_RTA96-C.htm), a two-stroke, fourteen cylinder 750MW monster used to power the ship [Emma Maersk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emma_M%C3%A6rsk). The manufacturer's specifications state a thermal efficiency of greater than 50%, which they define explicitly as the work output divided by the free energy of the fuel burning reaction. As we have seen above, this would imply an upper reservoir temperature of the order of $700K$ if it were reaching Carnot efficiency, which is still rather cooler than the likely initial temperature of the combustion products.

## Edit after More Reading and Thinking:

A closer reading of the Ganapathy reference cited above and some more thought on this interesting question leads to the following comments.

1. The steam output temperature of a modern powerstation superheater is likely to be of the order of $850{\rm K}$ to $900{\rm K}$ ($1100^o{\rm F}$) and this should be the figure we take as our upper reservoir temperature. I was taking the upper reservoir temperature to be that of the radiation in the superheater ($1300{\rm K}$), thinking that the difference between the gas and radiation temperature is an inefficiency that needs to be included. However, presumably we can think of the furnace as a system that is closed aside from the input of heat and the output of steam and that no other, or little other, energy is lost from the furnace system. Coincidentally, $850{\rm K}$ is also the temperature that the modern stainless steels used in turbine blades can withstand long term without creep (see the ["Efficiency" section of the Steam Engine Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_engine#Efficiency)). Also, one could legitimately argue that the question could be taken to be asking for the efficiency of the turbine alone, and not of the furnace - turbine system. This being so, $T_{max}=850{\rm K}$ would be a reasonable assumption.
2. Modern steam turbines actually have lower reservoir temperatures *below* $100^o{\rm C}$: they are sealed and their later stages work *below atmospheric pressure*. So the lower reservoir temperature $T_{\min}$ is more like $30^o{\rm C}$ : let's say $300K$.

With these figures, our turbine's potential Carnot efficiency would be:

$$\eta = 1-\frac{T_{min}}{T_{max}} = 1-\frac{300}{850} = 65\%$$

which, for a system on the upper end of the scale of the [Wikipedia's $33\%$ to $48\%$ estimates]((http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam-electric_power_station), implies a *working efficiency* (work output compared to the Carnot efficiency) of

$$0.5/0.65 = 77\%$$

So I would suggest this is a fairly good answer and as near to an answer as you're going to get on this forum, unless we hear from an energy technologist. So steam turbines do rather well. Interestingly, if we use the "experimental" Novikov formula you cited, we foretell an efficiency under these conditions of

$$1-\sqrt{\frac{300}{850}} = 41\%$$

so this is a little pessimistic for the modern steam turbine, which is the paragon of  modern efficiency in heat engines, with a great deal of research being input to the sophisticated computer control of supercritical superheaters and furnaces.

Answer (score 1):

The efficiency of heat engine cycle greatly depend on the individual processes that make up the cycle are executed. Thus cycle efficiency can be maximized by using the processes that require the least amount of work and deliver the most that is by using reversible process.
        In 1824 French engineer Sadi Carnot proposed best reversible cycle is Carnot cycle.In case Carnot engine the heat addition and rejection from the reservoir or a heat source to the engine and from engine to sink is at  constant temperature and reversible manner i.e. Reversible Isotherm condition due to which the total heat supplied is utilized or converted to the work with the help of engine and entropy generation is zero. Remaining Expansion and Compression process are also by reversible manner.
While in normal heat engine the process are become irreversible due to phenomenon like friction, vibration,heat losses etc. so the heat losses are more when it is compared with the carnot heat engine. Due to which Real heat engines always have lower efficiency than the Carnot efficiency.
A real engine efficiency can be increased by

1) Temperature at which heat is added i.e. source temperature so that losses are less as entropy generation is less.

2) Lowering the temperature of sink i.e temperature at which heat engine is rejecting heat