# How can I make the heat engine efficiency become 100%?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, heat-engine

Is it possible to make it 100%? Or in what kind of situation the heat engine efficiency could be 100%?

Comment: One that (A) reaches the theoretical maximum efficiency for its operating conditions and (B) uses a cold reservoir at absolute zero. (A) is a engineering impossibility and (B) is a plain old impossibility.

Comment: Please do some research! eg read [What's the efficiency of real heat engines?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114539) or [Why is the Carnot engine the most efficient?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149214)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows a complete lack of effort or research.

Answer (score 4):

According to Carnot's Theorem [Carnot's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot%27s_theorem_(thermodynamics)), the maximum efficiency of a cyclic heat machine working between a hot reservoir at absolute temperature $T_h$ and a cold reservoir at $T_c$ is $$\eta=\frac{W}{Q_h}=1-\frac{T_c}{T_h}$$ where $W$ is the work done and $Q_h$ is the heat entering the machine. Therefore, the efficiency increases for large $T_h$ and small $T_c$ and approaches $1$, i.e.100%,  for $T_c \to 0K$, which is, however not a practical working condition.